# Why 'return' is used in PHP , Codeigniter to retrive or insert data to database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in PHP as well as in Codeigniter.

```html
public function test_table()
{ 
    $q = $this->db
    ->where('id',$id)
    ->get('table_name');
    return $q->row();

}
// test_table() is a function written to models in codeigniter .
```

Can anyone please share me in details Why we are used **`return`**  statement to insert or retrieve data in database ?

Comment: Presumably this code is within the scope of a function?  And presumably this code is *returning* the value from that function?

Comment: Can you please post the whole example?

Comment: How else would you expect it to work? Why is this surprising?

Comment: my question is only about " return" - statement , why most of time we used return. If we not used RETURN then what will happen there ??

Comment: Without return null is returned implicitly in PHP.

Comment: @Biswajit17: So... You're asking what the `return` keyword means in PHP?  It sounds like an introductory tutorial to PHP would be a *great* place to start.

Comment: Why ? Because we want it, and we want to use the result for some reasons. This is *very* basic.

Comment: This sounds like your new to programming, welcome to the world of "what does this do" "what does that do". Please follow basic tutorials of the language you want to learn and then move over to frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the php manual:

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call

http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

That means the "return" statement will return the data to the parent method who called it.

The behavior of DB operations will depend on the frameworks/libraries you are using.

From the codeigniter manual:

```
insert([$table = ''[, $set = NULL[, $escape = NULL]]])
RETURNS: TRUE on success, FALSE on failure
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

When selecting, the "return" statement will return the row from the database or "false" if not found.